# Azure App Insights logging to both Exceptions and Traces in .Net core

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am looking for a way to log into both Traces and Exceptions. It seems it is easier to track if I log into both and looks like everyone prefers it. Unless there is a reason not to.

```
Logger.LogWarning(ex, "Audit failed");
Logger.LogWarning("Audit failed");
```

The first one logs into exceptions while the second one logs into traces. I would have to add it like this to a lot of places to log it into both.
Any other way I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually use 2 `Logger.LogWarning()` methods if we want to send logs both into `traces` and `exceptions`.

There is no direct way to do that. You can consider writing an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) which includes the 2 methods `Logger.LogWarning(ex, "Audit failed"); Logger.LogWarning("Audit failed");`. Then you can only call this Extension methods once and send logs into both `traces` and `exceptions`. The `Extension methods` like below:

```
public static class MyCustomLogger
{

    //define an extension method.
    public static void Custom_LogWarning(this ILogger logger, string msg)
    {
        //send this log into traces table
        logger.LogWarning(msg);

        //send this log into exceptions table
        logger.LogWarning(new Exception(), msg);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this extension method like below:

```
logger.Custom_LogWarning("it is a message from my custom log method...");
```